# WebPart not getting refreshed on changing properties from powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, content-editor-web-part

I edited the Content property of a Content Editor Web part via powershell but when I first view the page, it is not getting reflected. When i click edit once , I see my changes . What could the issue for the changes to the web part not getting reflected even on Page refresh ?

```
  Function EditProperties($SiteCollectionURL) {

    $Web = Get-SPWeb $SiteCollectionURL

    $PublishingWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)

    $PublishingPages = $PublishingWeb.GetPublishingPages()      

    foreach ($Page in $PublishingPages)
    {  
        $Page.CheckOut()

        $WebPartManager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($Page.Url,[System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

        foreach($webPart in $WebPartManager.WebParts)
        {

            if($webPart.GetType() -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart])
            {    

               if($webPart.Title.Equals("LinkWebPart")){

                  $oldXmlElement = $webPart.Content;
                  $oldXmlElement.InnerText =  'Edited Content here!';  
                  $webpart.Content = $oldXmlElement
                }

             $webPartManager.SaveChanges($webPart);
            }


}
    $page.CheckIn("CEWP Updated") 
    $Page.ListItem.File.Publish("CEWP Updated")
}
```

}

Comment: Code is absolutely fine. Have you added other webpart on page?

Comment: There are other web parts on the page too. Those don't need modifications from powershell. Only this web part gets updated from a powershell script

Comment: Yes, Other webparts are creating problem. Just for check, close other webparts and run powershell command.

Comment: I tried it on an empty page and It still did not get updated until I pressed the Edit page button once

Comment: Please check in Inspect tool (F12), is there any javascript error? I used same code. i am not getting any issue like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$xmlDoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$contentXml = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("Content") 

$contentXml.InnerText = 'Edited Content here!'
$webpart.Content = $contentXml
```

Comment: I have tried this. It didnt work.